# Keep image on same spot across different views

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to make an account signup series of pages, and I want my app icon (an image) to maintain the same spot across the pages, which currently they don't.

I've tried using spacers to even it out, but it hasn't worked.

First view:

```
 var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                VStack {
                    Image("logo")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()

                }

                VStack {
                    InformationTextField(iconName: "person.fill", headlineText: "USERNAME", textFieldDescription: "Enter username here", protected: false)
                    InformationTextField(iconName: "lock.fill", headlineText: "PASSWORD", textFieldDescription: "Enter password here", protected: true)
                    NavigationLink(destination: Text(
                        "ee")) {
                            ActionButton(text: "signup")
                }
                    Divider()
                        .background(Color("DividerColor"))
                    Text("Don't have an account?")
                        .fontWeight(.light)
                    NavigationLink(destination: SignupPage()) {
                        ActionButton(text: "sign up")
                    }

                }


            }
        .padding()
        }
    }
```

Second View:

```
   var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                VStack {
                    Image("logo")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
                }

                VStack {
                    InformationTextField(iconName: "person.fill", headlineText: "USERNAME", textFieldDescription: "Enter username here", protected: false)
                    InformationTextField(iconName: "info.circle.fill", headlineText: "CONTACT", textFieldDescription: "Enter email or phone number here", protected: false)
                    InformationTextField(iconName: "calendar", headlineText: "AGE", textFieldDescription: "Enter birthday here", protected: false)
                    InformationTextField(iconName: "lock.fill", headlineText: "PASSWORD", textFieldDescription: "Enter password here", protected: true)
                    InformationTextField(iconName: "lock.fill", headlineText: "CONFIRM PASSWORD", textFieldDescription: "Re-enter password here", protected: true)
                }
//                .padding()
            NavigationLink(destination: Text(
                "ee")) {
                    ActionButton(text: "sign up")
                }


            }
        .padding()
        }
    }
```

I want the logo image to be in the exact same spot on the screen, no matter the view. Everything I have tried doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You probably should try ZStack

Comment: What do you mean by that? To reduce code, or fix the issue?